# Rails Paperclip cannot save attachment with accented characters in file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding, paperclip

Using Windows, with Rails v3.2.11, Ruby v1.9.3p0, latest stable version of Paperclip AFAIK.

File name: **"2011-rosé-750mL.png"**

I'm trying to update my website and in the process I need to move all of the images that paperclip stored (originals) to a different location. So essentially I'm reading each original file and setting the attachment, then running save on the model. Clearly paperclip doesn't have any problems saving an uploaded file with the accented characters, but when saving a new file by referencing the name with accented characters, something bad happens.

example:

```
w = Wine.find(19)
w.photo = File.open("D:/Files/Websites/rails3.website/public/images/store/products/original/2011-rosé-750mL.png", 'rb')
w.save :validate => false
```

Most of the upgrade process works until I get to a file with the name mentioned above. The error I get is: No such file or directory - .../2011-rosé-750mL

[image]

All I can think of is that it has to do with the file's character encoding in the name - such that when paperclip tries to read the file upon saving, it doesn't use the right characters. `File.open(source, 'rb')` actually works (doesn't throw any errros), it's just when saving the model does this error crop up. Looking at the error message, it's referencing the save directory for the originals, not the directory I'm reading from when I execute `File.open()`; so it's somewhere up the line but seemingly out of my control (Paperclip internals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on trh's response, I decided to rename all files through the use of the function `ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate`. Also, Paperclip files are now transliterated by default (no longer using accented characters in file names).

Answer (score 0):

It is a character encoding issue.  I have used this gem:

https://github.com/saepia/paperclip-strip-strange-characters

Which was very effective, however I'm not sure the results you'll get with those versions of ruby and rails.  Worth a shot.